# iterating over unknown XML structure with PHP (DOM)

Tags: php, xml, arrays, parsing, loops

I want to write a function that parses a (theoretically) unknown XML data structure into an equivalent PHP array.

Here is my sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<content>

<title>Sample Text</title>

<introduction>
    <paragraph>This is some rudimentary text</paragraph>
</introduction>
<description>
    <paragraph>Here is some more text</paragraph>
    <paragraph>Even MORE text</paragraph>
    <sub_section>
        <sub_para>This is a smaller, sub paragraph</sub_para>
        <sub_para>This is another smaller, sub paragraph</sub_para>
    </sub_section>
</description>
</content>
```

I modified this DOM iterating function from devarticles:

```
$data = 'path/to/xmldoc.xml';
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument(); #create a DOM element
$xmlDoc->load( $data ); #load data into the element
$xmlRoot = $xmlDoc->firstChild; #establish root

function xml2array($node)
    {
    if ($node->hasChildNodes())
    {
$subNodes = $node->childNodes;
    foreach ($subNodes as $subNode)
        {
        #filter node types
        if (($subNode->nodeType != 3) || (($subNode->nodeType == 3)))   
            {
            $arraydata[$subNode->nodeName]=$subNode->nodeValue;
            }
         xml2array($subNode);
         }
      }
      return $arraydata;
   }
//The getNodesInfo function call

 $xmlarray = xml2array($xmlRoot);


// print the output - with a little bit of formatting for ease of use...
foreach($xmlarray as $xkey)
     {
     echo"$xkey<br/><br/>";
     }
```

Now, because of the way I'm passing the elements to the array I'm overwriting any elements that share a node name (since I ideally want to give the keys the same names as their originating nodes). My recursion isn't great... However, even if I empty the brackets - the second tier of nodes are still coming in as *values* on the first tier (see the text of the description node).

Anyone got any ideas how I can better construct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might also want to check out XML Unserializer

http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Serializer/redirected

Answer (score 2):

You might be better off just snagging some code off the net

http://www.bin-co.com/php/scripts/xml2array/

```
    /**
     * xml2array() will convert the given XML text to an array in the XML structure.
     * Link: http://www.bin-co.com/php/scripts/xml2array/
     * Arguments : $contents - The XML text
     *                $get_attributes - 1 or 0. If this is 1 the function will get the attributes as well as the tag values - this results in a different array structure in the return value.
     *                $priority - Can be 'tag' or 'attribute'. This will change the way the resulting array sturcture. For 'tag', the tags are given more importance.
     * Return: The parsed XML in an array form. Use print_r() to see the resulting array structure.
     * Examples: $array =  xml2array(file_get_contents('feed.xml'));
     *              $array =  xml2array(file_get_contents('feed.xml', 1, 'attribute'));
     */
    function xml2array($contents, $get_attributes=1, $priority = 'tag') {
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [SimpleXML](http://de.php.net/simplexml) or [xml_parse_into_struct](http://de.php.net/xml_parse_into_struct).

$arraydata is neither passed to subsequent calls to xml2array() nor is the return value used, so yes "My recursion isn't great..." is true ;-)
To append a new element to an existing array you can use empty square brackets, $arr[] = 123; $arr[$x][] = 123;

Comment: I did make a method that passes the array back in, but I want to figure out why it's not seeing those 2nd tier nodes. Also, how does one keep adding that last set of empty parentheses on an array of unknown depth?